# ngx-editor - custom button supporting <small> tag

Tags: angular, ngx-editor

I saw plugins and schema in the documentation (https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/en/introduction/) but I don't really understand how to add my own button to the toolbar. If  can't be done, maybe a div with a class?

My implementation in Angular 15:

```
export class WysiwygEditorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() value!: string;
  @Output() valueChanged = new EventEmitter<string>();
  editor!: Editor;
  toolbar: Toolbar = [
    ['bold', 'italic'],
    ['underline', 'strike'],
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.editor = new Editor();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.editor.destroy();
  }
}
```